# how to make a border area go around the content of a page where there is a footer fixed to the bottom of the page and an header fixed to the top

Tags: html, css

consider the following:

http://jsfiddle.net/PxabT/10/

There are 3 divs hd, bd, ft. hd is fixed to the top. ft is fixed to the bottom.

I want the lime colored border to go totally around the white central area without increasing the height of the ft or hd divs.

How do I achieve that?

Many thanks!

edit: see http://jsfiddle.net/PxabT/15/ which is a step forward by changing the borders to padding.

Comment: Put everything into another div and give that div the lime background color

Comment: @Richard. Tried it. It didn't work.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/fwGm7/ that should be fine ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually like this solution better. Add fixed left and right bars. Then use padding to keep content area from flowing into them. It is also very similar to your current code.

http://jsfiddle.net/PxabT/46/

```
body{
   margin: 0;
   padding: 0;
}
#left { position: fixed; height: 100%; width: 10px; left: 0; background-color: lime; }
#right { position: fixed; height: 100%; width: 10px; right: 0; background-color: lime; }
#bd{
    padding-top: 40px;
    padding-left: 10px;
    padding-right: 10px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone for contributing. I think this answer is the cleanest and has no undesired side effects :)

Answer (score 1):

<strike>Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/PxabT/11/)?

(I used red so you can see it better)</strike>

Edit:
I've fixed the top part as well (no way it would've worked without this)... see [here](http://jsfiddle.net/PxabT/13/)

Comment: no. the green lines should connect. imagine you have a pen and you extend the extend the green lines already on the page straight all the way until there is a green rectangle around the white middle area without making the top or bottom divs thicker.

Comment: Ah, got it... try adding min-height: 1000px; for example to the central element... however, you'll need to work on the overflow (scrollbar) then... any better?

Comment: and if the content in that div is less the 1000px in height? or at a larger screen he might need more then 1000px height.. for ex: try zooming out your last example on jsfiddle and see that the page brakes up form the footer.

Comment: I know, I know, this is a tough one to beat, go ahead if you have a better solution... What I can say for larger screens is to put min-height at some huuuge number, like 9999, and disable the y-axis overflow... Still depends what he needs it for.

Comment: thanks. Your answer was pretty clever, but i think there is a simple solution out there that is eluding us :)

Comment: You're welcome! Page 'verticality' is always a problem. I have another idea if you want: you could use JS to calculate page dimensions and place the elements accordingly, but personally, I'd always go with CSS for that kind of stuff.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this, much closer.

http://jsfiddle.net/PxabT/21/

The only that annoys me is that I have to use height: 100%; on #bd. This means you will always have scrollbars on the page, even if content is short.

Basically we give bg-color to body, set content bg to white and use fixed height header and footer. Then we can use offsets to get things to be correct on content div.

```
html, body { height: 100%; width: 100%; background-color: lime;}
#hd { width: 100%; position: fixed; height: 50px; top: 0; background-color: lime; }
#ft { width: 100%; position: fixed; height: 50px; bottom: 0; background-color: lime; }
#bd { min-height: 100%; margin-top: 50px; margin-bottom: 50px; background-color: white; margin-left: 10px; margin-right: 10px; }
```

Comment: and with more content you got this http://jsfiddle.net/PxabT/27/ , but hwo knows, might be good to solve his problem

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/PxabT/43/

this I have tested with more text and less.. and the scroll apears only when content height is bigger then 100%

Comment: allright.. I managed to get the main container height to the footer and the scoll appears when content is bigger the the container's height. this is where I give up if this still is no good.